# R: Comparing two binary vectors

Tags: r

Im new to R.
I have two vectors of zeros and ones.
I want to find which rows are both zeros, both ones. zeros to one or one to zeros. I cannot seem to find a question considering this. Thanks

ex.

```
  a=c(0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1)
  b=c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1)
```

Comment: What would the desired output be?

Comment: The goal is some kind of hit rate table. so i only need the total amount of the 4 situations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `table`...

```
table( a , b )
   b
a   0 1
  0 2 3
  1 3 2
```

Comment: (+1) This is awesome. I need to go back and clean up some of my code.

Comment: @TylerRinker good point. It's a little unclear if the OP is looking for the rate or the total number of *events* for each situation.

Answer (score 1):

to make a **distinction between cases**, you can use `&` operator, so, to find a case when a==X and b==Y:

```
which( (a==X) & (b==Y) )
```

eg.

```
which( (a==0) & (b==0) )
```

prints out

```
[1] 2 5
```

while

```
which( (a==1) & (b==0) )
```

prints

```
[1] 4 6 7
```

etc.

If the problem does not concern symmetries (we just want to find indices with the same/different values), one can use simple comparisions and `which`:

This is exactly what `==` is for

```
a==b
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

and if you need indices, there is a `which` function

```
which( a==b )
[1]  2  5  8 10
```

for 0->1 or 1->0 case we can use `!=` operator

```
which( a!=b )
[1] 1 3 4 6 7 9
```

Comment: I want to make a distinction between 0=0 and 1=1

Comment: In some cases this approach may be useful but in keeping with the poster's intention I think it may not be as efficient as the `table` approach.

Comment: table is just a summarization, while this approach gives you indices, these are two orthogonal methods, depending on the need. In the question we have "I want to find which rows...", table does not answet this